# Where can I examine or manage PubSub topics create using Google Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-pubsub

I created a scheduled function with Firebase. Deployed it. I do not know where I could see the log written in my function or at least the pubsub topics. This is the output of `firebase deploy`:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
!  functions: missing required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com. Enabling now...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (49.94 KB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function addMessage(us-central1)...
i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function scheduledFunction(us-central1)...
i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function every10secs(us-central1)...
+  functions[addMessage(us-central1)] Successful create operation.
```

Since neither the emulator emulates scheduled function nor the Firebase console displays the scheduled functions I am stuck. I assume I have to switch to the google cloud platform, but how?

Comment: finally found the PubSub inside Google Cloud Platform console. The intermix between firebase and GCP is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to know that you were able to find PubSub inside GCP. The reason is because FireBase tools [share some products](https://firebase.google.com/firebase-and-gcp) with Google Cloud Platform. I'm leaving this answer as step by step guide and reference for other users that may encounter this issue.

**PUBSUB on Google Cloud Platform**

To access PUBSUB:

1. Go to Navegation Menu on Google Cloud Platform.
2. Scroll until you reach BIGDATA > PUB/SUB, click on it.
3. Success! the PUB/SUB page will load with its options.

Note: You can 'pin' your most used products in the Navigation Menu.
For more details about the PUBSUB, [click here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console).

**Logs on Google Cloud Platform**

To see operation logs:

1. Go to Navegation Menu on Google Cloud Platform.
2. Scroll until you reach OPERATIONAL > Logging, click on it.
3. Success! the Logging page will load and you will be able to see logs of your different google products.

Note: Logs will need to be streamed into the log explorer first. Logging will suggest jobs to do this operation automatically. For more details about the Logging, [click here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console).